# Using worksheet name as variable, but with refresh ability

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formulas

O.!

I'm here for help to fix, what i think, it's a simple problem.

In a worksheet, I'm referring to some of the cells in the worksheet that is named, "Consolidado", but, because of some code, the sheet("Consolidado") gets deleted and is created again with new data, and because of it I get the "#REF" error in the formula on another worksheet, every time i run the code. Is there a way to "fix", force it to be "Consolidado" in the reference for the formula?

This is the formula.

Where `#REF` should be `"Consolidado"`.

```
PROC(2;1/--(#REF!$J$2:$J$30<>"");#REF!$J$2:$J$30)
```

ANY help is welcomed, again, thanks in adavance!

**=========EDIT==========**

The macro I use to "refresh" the sheet "Consolidado" follows bellow:

This macro creates a new summary every time a hit the button "Consolidar". But, before creating the new one, it destroy the old sheet to be sure the data is new.

---

```
Sub Consolidar_Abas()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Newsh As Worksheet
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim ColNum As Integer
    Dim RwNum As Long
    Dim Basebook As Workbook

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Delete the sheet "Consolidado" if it exist
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidado").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "Consolidado"
    Set Basebook = ThisWorkbook
    Set Newsh = Basebook.Worksheets.Add
    Newsh.Name = "Consolidado"

    'Add headers
    Newsh.Range("A1:AH1").Value = Array("Consolidado", "Carteira", "Segmento", "QTD Estagiário", "QTD CLT", "QTD Coordenador", "QTD Supervisor", "QTD BKO", "Prêmio & Comissões", "Receita Bruta Prevista", "Imposto", "Receita Líquida (-Imposto)", "Pessoal (OPs Carteira)", "Holding Carteira (Sup+Coord+BKO)", "Postagem & Impressos", "SMS", "Telefonia", "Internet Dedicada", "Softwares Dedicados", "Custo Extra", "Internet", "Softwares & Ferramentas", "Custo Total de Produção", "Lucro / Perda Prod. - Líquido", "Margem com Rec. Líquida", "Adm Holding", "Desp. Terceiros / Produção", "Tecnologia", "Manutenção", "Admistração", "Custo Empresarial Total", "Custo Total Real Final", "Lucro / Perda Final", "Margem com Rec. Líquida")

    'The links to the first sheet will start in row 2
    RwNum = 1

    For Each Sh In Basebook.Worksheets
        If Sh.Name <> Newsh.Name And Sh.Visible And Sh.Name <> "Menu" And Sh.Name <> "Infos" And Sh.Name <> "Master" Then
            ColNum = 1
            RwNum = RwNum + 1

    'Copy the sheet name in the A column
    Newsh.Cells(RwNum, 1).Value = Sh.Name
    For Each myCell In Sh.Range("A2:H2,J2:L2,A7:M7,A12:F12,H12,J12:K12")  '<--Change the range
            ColNum = ColNum + 1
            Newsh.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Formula = _
            "='" & Sh.Name & "'!" & myCell.Address(False, False)
            Next myCell

        End If
    Next Sh

    Newsh.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With


End Sub
```

---

In another sheet, called "Menu" I present the workbook, there are rules there and other text on how to operate de workbook and similar stuff also, the same in "Infos", just a bunch of other tool.

On "Menu" where the user can create a new form, that, after he fills it, will populate the sheet "Consolidado", every time he hits the button "Criar Nova Aba", will create a new form (I just creates a copy  from the sheet "Master") to be filled.

And after he finish the creation of many sheet as he want, he presses the "Consolidar" button, deleting the old one and creating a new "Consolidar" sheet.

I guess with this i cover the functioning of the Workbook. I'll try to make a blank version, unfortunately, it's from work and has sensitive data.

**EDIT 2**

What I'm needing now, on the cells, the respective formula:

Sheet: "Menu" ; Cell:AY4

```
=PROC(2;1/--(Consolidado!$J$2:$J$30<>"");Consolidado!$J$2:$J$30)
```

Sheet: "Menu" ; Cell:AY5

```
=PROC(2;1/--(Consolidado!$AF$2:$AF$30<>"");Consolidado!$AF$2:$AF$30)
```

Sheet: "Menu" ; Cell:AY6

```
=(PROC(2;1/--(Consolidado!$X$2:$X$30<>"");Consolidado!$X$2:$X$30))/(PROC(2;1/--(Consolidado!$L$2:$L$30<>"");Consolidado!$L$2:$L$30))
```

Sheet: "Menu" ; Cell:AY7

```
=(PROC(2;1/--(Consolidado!$AG$2:$AG$30<>"");Consolidado!$AG$2:$AG$30))/(PROC(2;1/--(Consolidado!$J$2:$J$30<>"");Consolidado!$J$2:$J$30))
```

Anything else, just ask. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Stop deleting the worksheet "Consolidado", and just change the data on it.

Comment: Tried, unfortunately it didin't work. I guess because, like i said, the WS gets deleted.  I can try again.

Comment: @mooseman it was a miracle to get that work. If you have a similar solution i would like to hear.

Comment: Make the formulas for the referencing sheets inside of VBA, so when you open the workbook, it runs the code and populates the formulas to reference Sheets("Consolidado").  You can either have formulas to reference, or you can have only values in the referencing sheets.  In either case, a macro would need to execute to get that update, since the source sheet is removed.

Comment: @Cyril, Thank you for the idea. I was trying something like this. I could do 2 things: 1, put a button to "insert" the formula on the summary with this code:  **'Sub Worksheets("Menu").Range("Ay4").Formula = "" = """PROC(2;1/--(Consolidado!$J$2:$J$30<>"""");Consolidado!$J$2:$J$30)""" End Sub'**   
 that "prints" the formula, and 2, created a function **'Function EVal(Ref As String) Application.Volatile EVal = Evaluate(Ref) End Function'**   that turn this text into a function, but didn't work, do you have any other ideia =/ ? thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried something which appears to work...

```
Sheets("").Columns("A").Replace What:="#REF!", Replacement:="Consolidado!", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
```

Make sure to change the column and the add a sheet reference.

Comment: It almost work! Like, in the first time a ran the macro, it was smooth and clear. But, closing and opening it again e runing it didn't worl =/
Can you help write a code to literlly insert the formulas on 4 specifc cels? In cell AY4 i need: '=PROC(2;1/--(Consolidado!$J$2:$J$30<>"");Consolidado!$J$2:$J$30)'.   On AY5: '=PROC(2;1/--(Consolidado!$AF$2:$AF$30<>"");Consolidado!$AF$2:$AF$30)'. On AY6: '=(PROC(2;1/--(Consolidado!$X$2:$X$30<>"");Consolidado!$X$2:$X$30))/(PROC(2;1/--(Consolidado!$L$2:$L$30<>"");Consolidado!$L$2:$L$30))'

Comment: And in AY7: '=(PROC(2;1/--(Consolidado!$AG$2:$AG$30<>"");Consolidado!$AG$2:$AG$30))/(PROC(2;1/--(Consolidado!$J$2:$J$30<>"");Consolidado!$J$2:$J$30))'. Again, thank you very very much for the quicky response!

Comment: @PauloAraújo There's a lot of missing information that would go into this.  if you can update your post to include the formulas (very hard to read in a comment), that would be of help.  I would also recommend trying to build the formulas yourself, using Sheets("").Range("AY2:AY" & lastRow).Formula = "=CALCULATION".  That would help people review more easily.  TO help with the formulas, for every " in your formula, you need "" listed, which opens and closes the formula in the VBA module.

Comment: @PauloAraújo specific to my posted answer, that should work every time.  I copied that from some of my working code and put in your sheet name.  Did you ensure that the modifications you made to the code (your sheet name and the appropriate column/range) were used when you closed and re-opened?

Comment: I'll check again the first formula. But after saving the file and opening again, it didn't work.
I updated the question, please, check to see if it helps. 
Is there an article/site that explain how to produce tose calculations? I really want to understand how can I make it too. Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: I came back to thank you, after struggling with it in the beginning now it's working like a charm! I guess it was not working properly on friday because i had 2 macros that delete the sheet "Consolidado", now I removed one of them e it's working smoothly. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Does the sheet you're looking for have a unique set of column headers?
Once you open the spreadsheet to process you can loop through the sheets looking for Consolidado

```
    'Find if sheet exists
    vFound = "N"
    For ix = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If "Consolidado" = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ix).Name Then
            vFound = "Y"
        End If
    Next
```

If the sheet is not there you could utilize the same idea to look for identifying column headers, just enough to be sure you have the correct sheet:

```
    'Check column names of sheets to find desired sheet (note vFound is still "N")
    For ix = 1 To Sheets.Count
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ix).Activate
        If "Name" = Range("A1:A1").Value And "URL" = Range("B1:B1").Value And "Date" = Range("C1:C1").Value And "Logon" = Range("D1:D1").Value Then
            vTotFound = "Y"
            vSheetName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ix).Name
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

You can use vSheetName instead of Consolidado.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it and feedback you ASAP. Thanks again"

Comment: Hello Jan. I updated on the post above, I fixed my problem with the solution provided by Cyril. I really appreciate your support. I will save this option for future projects (and problems of course :) )! Thanks alot for your time and help!

Comment: Thank you for the response - and glad was able to give you food for thought.